# server.on is not a function when migrating from hapi 16 to 17

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to migrate my nodejs code using hapi 16.1.1 to 17.7.0 (the upgrade in hapi dependency is motivated by vulnerability raised by `npm audit`).

The following code works in 16.1.1:

```
server = new hapi.Server();

server.on('log', function (event, tags) {
  ...
});
```

However, with 17.7.0 I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: server.on is not a function
```

I guess that old server.on() should have some equivalente in hapi 17, but I haven't find migration documentation from v16 to v17.

Any help on how to solve this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's in the release notes https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3658

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm self-anwering my question so other users may benefit from this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin B suggestion (thanks!) I have changed the code this way:

```
server.events.on('log', function (event, tags) {
  ...
}
```

and it works.